# Azure hosted agent crystal report

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am using hosted build and its failing with error, can not find the assembly crystal report. How can I use crystal report using hosted build agent?

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that hosted agents do not come with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio installed, the COM components are not required to perform a compile. All you need to build are copies of the .NET DLLs that your application references.

One workaround is to add the DLLs you reference to the repository and do a conditional hint path to use them when they are not installed in the default location on the machine.

```
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll')">..\..\lib\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll')">..\..\lib\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll')">..\..\lib\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll')">..\..\lib\CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Here, the DLLs were placed in a folder named `lib` at the root of the repository. The `!Exists` condition checks whether the DLL is at the default location, and if not will switch to using the local one in the `lib` folder.

Alternatively, rather than checking binaries into your repository you could host them on a private NuGet feed or a MyGet feed. Do note that there are also [unofficial copies of these libraries on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=crystaldecisions) that you could reference, but it is often not clear what version of the binaries the package authors have submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal report can not build by Hosted agent since the Hosted agent not installed Crystal reports for visual studio.

You should build the crystal report by [**private agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) which installs the Crystal reports for visual studio.